# what does "not all control paths return a value” mean in this program?

Tags: c, function, if-statement, binary-search, cs50

I wrote a code that takes inputs until an EOF integer (999999 in this case) is typed. Then it sorts the numbers and searches for our needle (an integer) in that array of integers (called haystack). Now I am facing a problem in my searching algorithm. While compiling it shows me a warning:

> 'search': not all control paths return a value

I think it means that the function might not return anything in some cases but the problem is that i can't think of any such case. I even checked my program with a lot of values and it always gave me the correct output. Can anyone help me figure out where the problem lies. I was use some **windows native tools compiler** for this.

Also if anyone has seen the **CS50 pset3 find problem** which is related to this, I used the same search function there too but while compiling the code in **CS50 IDE** the program never showed whether it found the needle in haystack. It only arranged them in increasing order and then stopped after that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cs50.h"
#include <stdlib.h>


bool search(int value, int values[], int n);
void sort(int values[], int n);

// maximum amount of hay
#define MAX 65536

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./find needle\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // remember needle
    int needle = atoi(argv[1]);

    // fill haystack
    int size;
    int haystack[MAX];
    for (size = 0; size < MAX; size++)
    {
        // wait for hay until EOF
        printf("\nhaystack[%i] = ", size);
        int straw = GetInt();
        if (straw == 999999)
        {
            break;
        }

        // add hay to stack
        haystack[size] = straw;
    }
    printf("\n");

    // sort the haystack
    sort(haystack, size);

    // try to find needle in haystack
    if (search(needle, haystack, size))
    {
        printf("\nFound needle in haystack!\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nDidn't find needle in haystack.\n\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns true if value is in array of n values, else false.
 */
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    /* TODO: implement a searching algorithm */
    int first = 0;
    int last = n;
    int middle = (first + last) / 2;

    while (first + 1 < last)
    {
        if (value == values[middle])
        {
            return true;
            break;
        }
        if (value == values[first])
        {
            return true;
            break;
        }
        if (value == values[last])
        {
            return true;
            break;
        }        
        if (value < values[middle])
        {
            last = middle;
            middle = (first + last) / 2;
        }
        if (value > values[middle])
        {
            first = middle;
            middle = (first + last) / 2;
        }
    }
    if (first + 1 >= last)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Sorts array of n values.
 */
void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    // TODO: implement an O(n^2) sorting algorithm
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++)
        {
            if( values[i + 1] < values[i])
            {
                int b = values[i + 1];
                values[i + 1] = values[i];
                values[i] = b;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        printf("haystack[%d] = %d ", k, values[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It means you have a function that has promised to return a value of a given type, for example, bool, and that there are paths the code can take inside the function where no value will be returned.

Comment: `if (first + 1 >= last)` is pointless. That's how you exited the while-loop above. Just use `return false;`

Comment: BTW `int last = n;` --> `int last = n-1;`

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the future.

Comment: @WhozCraig But then say it found our number and it returns true and breaks out of the do loop. But then it would reach the return false block and further return false too. So the function would return both true and false which would be weird.

Comment: Apart from above comments about program logic, `if (first + 1 >= last)` returns `false` but no value is returned otherwise. *That* is what compiler is complaining about.

Comment: Your code has several problems. E.g. the `break` directly after a `return` statement is never been reached, because the `return` already exists the current function.

Comment: @cwschmidt Thanks for the answer. I understood what I was doing wrong. I have to remove the break line code and also remove the the if condition in return false and my code becomes correct. Also is my algorithm correct?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not execute your code. It does not do value tracking. While **you** can reason about the values of variables and expressions, this is generally an unsolvable problem **for the compiler**.

Your compiler tells you that it doesn't know what to return from `search` when control reaches the function's closing `}`.

BTW, it is a bad idea to write a function named `sort`, since the C Standard Library contains a function with the same name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood what I was doing wrong. I have to remove the break line code and also remove the the if condition in return false and my code becomes correct. Also is my algorithm correct?